# Any way to delete or move published pages in Publication

Tags: 2011, publishing

Is there any way to delete or move published pages.

I have many publication targets, I don't know if we could find publication targets to which page is published.

There are some unwanted pages in my publication which I am using no more. So I thought I would delete them.

I am using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is most certainly by design, it should be impossible to move a page if the page is published to a specific location.

You have three options - the third one I wouldn't do, but it's there:

1) Unpublish the pages and then move them to the desired location, then republish

2) Create copies of the pages and publish them - then simply unpublish and delete the original pages.

3) **Not recommended, but letting you know what's possible -**  It's possible to rename the structure group paths and then republish the pages

I certainly recommend option 2 as the safest way, but this could raise some questions on the implementation too.

Also, if you've changed publication target configurations over time, the 'published' flags could be messed up.  Have look at this question for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934210/tridion-the-item-is-published-unable-to-delete-page-error-when-page-has-bee

Comment: Thank you for the response. Actually the page has been published to many targets. Is there any way to know the publication targets to which the page actually has been published to.

Comment: Please post a new question for this topic. Just so we keep good separation of questions and answers

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There are so many publication targets. I would like to know if there any method to delete from database directly.

Answer (score 7):

You mentioned "I don't know if we could find publication targets to which page is published."

You can certainly see which publication target each page is published to by doing a "Where Used" on it and clicking "Published to":

[image]

And since the GUI is able to show this, then surely you can write a Core Service script to automatically spit out a report for each page.  After this, you can follow one of the approaches suggested by @John in his answer.

Comment: Although it's a valid answer, it's not an answer to the question that was asked. I encourage Patan to create a new question and then please move this answer to it

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way to delete or move published pages.

Out of the box => Other than unpublishing them - No. As John describes this is *by design*.

> There are some unwanted pages in my publication which I am using no more. So I thought I would delete them.

Alternatively you can create a dummy target, pointing to an empty deployer and unpublish from there - this approach is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690335/what-are-the-steps-to-remove-a-publication-target-in-tridon

Once Tridion understands the pages to be properly unpublished you can, of course, delete as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I have so many targets. Creating this will be real big task for me. Can we directly remove from db.

Comment: "directly remove from db" - only through agreement or more likely hotfix provision from Tridion Support (or risk invalidation of support agreement). Alternatively look to complete the 2011 'MarkAsPublished' PowerTool that existed in 2009 - aimed as marking items - programatically through the supported API - as unpublished. https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/